# How can Python read this file faster than my hard drive?

Tags: python, macos, file-io

How is Python able to read files faster than the theoretical maximum speed of my hard drive (Mac Mini sporting SSD)? `bigfile` is 3.22 GB file of completely random data, and the hard disk read speed according to QuickBench is < 500 MB/s.

```
t0 = time.perf_counter()
f = open('/Volumes/V/bigfile', 'rb')
checksum = 1
bites = f.read(1048576)
while bites:
    checksum = zlib.adler32(bites, checksum)
    bites = f.read(1048576)

print('Checksum: %s, Time taken: %s' % (checksum, time.perf_counter() - t0))
```

Prints: Checksum: 520807048, Time taken: 0.8804108270001052

This is just not possible! What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file is in your operating system's disk cache, which is stored in RAM.  RAM is fast.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know of a way of clearing operating system disk cache on OSX? I had no idea it would or could cache a >3GB file.

Comment: @HorseloverFat: The amount of data cached is limited only by the amount of RAM your computer has.  I'm guessing you have at least 8 GB.  Run the "purge" command as root to clear your disk cache.  You will notice a significant performance decrease in all applications after you run this command until the cache warms up again.

Comment: @HorseloverFat: quick solution: reboot. cache won't survive the boot.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options, how this can happen:

- The file is already in the filesystem cache and you get it directly from RAM
- The file is compressed by the filesystem and so you only need to transfer less bytes (in fact, HFS+ does that since 10.6, see http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=780570 for some scripts to inspect things and an explanation)
- You do the measurement inside a VM and your timer is simply measuring the wrong thing, VMWare even has a whole whitepaper about that kind of error (e.g. http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/Timekeeping-In-VirtualMachines.pdf it is similar for other VM systems)